# ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(19,25): error TS2339: Property 'getUsers' does not exist on type 'Dataservice'

Tags: angular, angular6

I am new to Angular,

Trying to create function that will fetch record from MongoDB database, however getting an issue. API URL is working fine.

**File: data.services.spec.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()

export class DataService {

  result:any;

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this._http.get("/api/users")
          .map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
  }

}
```

**File: app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Import the Http Module and our Data Service
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [ DataService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**File: app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// Import the DataService
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'mean';

    // Define a users property to hold our user data
    users: Array<any>;
    // Create an instance of the DataService through dependency injection
    constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { 
      // Access the Data Service's getUsers() method we defined
      this._dataService.getUsers()
          .subscribe(res => this.users = res);
    }
}
```

Error is here `this._dataService.getUsers()`.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: @manish `error TS2339: Property 'getUsers' does not exist on type 'Dataservice'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write service in **data.services.ts** not in **data.services.spec.ts**

in `data.services.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';


import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()

export class DataService {

  result:any;

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get("/api/users")
          .map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
  }

}
```

in component:

```
import { DataService } from './data.service';
```

Comment: Thank you. that helped. Error occurred cause I misplaced my code. Working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

find the example in below link

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkatdm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

you are using data.services.spec.ts instead of data.services.ts,spec.ts extention is for testing 
hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that is true. I read article for `spec.ts` requirement. Now cleared.
Thank you